# Ошибка:exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова. С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, поиск, динамические-массивы

Код является заданием из практики. Задание заключается в написание и применении линейного поиска на массиве состоящем от 6 мил. до 8 мил. с шагом в 1 мил. И все вроде работает, но появляется ошибка и я не могу понять почему...

[image: Ошибка]

[image: Ошибка]

Вот код:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int search(int key, int arr[], int numb) {
    int c=0;
    double time = clock(); //Время в начале поиска
    for (int i = 0; i <= numb-1; i++) {
        c++;
        if (arr[i]==key) {          
            cout <<"Количество сравнений: " << c<<"\nВремя поиска: "<< (clock() - time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " секунд.\n";           
            return i;
        }
    }
    cout << "Количество сравнений: " << c << "\nВремя поиска: " << (clock() - time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " секунд.\n";
    return -1;
}
void LineSerch(int key, int arr[], int numb) {
    int f;
    f= search(key, arr, numb);
    if (f > -1) {
        cout << "Число находится в элементе с номером: " << f+1<<endl;
    }
    if (f == -1) {
        cout << "Такого числа нет.\n";
    }
}
void write(int col, string text) {
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("file.txt");
    for (int i = 1; i <= col; i++) {
        fout << text;
    }
    fout.close();
}
int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int number,key,t=0;
    int arr[10];
    cout << "Введите тестовый массив из 10 элементов\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    cout << "Введите число для поиска:\n";
    LineSerch(2, arr, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        cout << arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    string text = "5";
    write(70, text);

    for (int n = 6000000; n <= 8000000; n = n + 1000000) {
        int* b = new int[n];
        t++;
        cout << "\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n" << "n" << t << " = " << n << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) b[i] = rand();
        cout << "Введите число для поиска: ";
        cin >> key;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (i == n / 2 - 1) { b[i]=2; }
            else { b[i] = 1; }
        }
        LineSerch(key, b, n);





        cout << "\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
        delete[] b;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как минимум -

```
int* b = new int[n];

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (i == n / 2 - 1) { b[i]=2; }
        else { b[i] = 1; }
```

Итого - запись за пределами массива (`i` в `b[i]` не может быть равно `n`).

Comment: В задумке это должно было ставить 2 в центр массива для того чтобы можно было сделать поиск среднего случая

Comment: Да неважно, что вы задумали - вы пишете за пределами массива. Что ни при какой задумке не может быть правильно...

Comment: Понял, огромное спасибо.. Затупил.